# ActiveX component can't create object: what happens to classes that don't have a namespace when the dll is registered?

Tags: c#, dll, com, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a fairly complex dll which contains two namespaces, as well as a few classes that do not belong to a namespace at all.

For the sake of simplicity, I have a test dll which has two classes in it:

```
namespace MyAsmNamespace{
    public MyClass{
       public int doSomething(){ return 1;}
    }
}
```

and

```
public MySecondClass{
    public int doSomethingElse(){ return 2;}
}
```

I am trying to use objects from this dll within a classic ASP page, using CreateObject.

I have registered the dll using `>RegAsm.exe /codebase /tlb`

And then I load the dll using `set obj = CreateObject("MyAsmNamespace.MyClass")`

Now the classes with namespaces specified work just fine, but for the class that doesn't have a namespace, I don't know what to do.  I tried `set obj = CreateObject("MySecondClass")`, but that doesn't work (I get an ActiveX Component Can't Create Object error)

I looked in IL DASM, and MySecondClass is in the assembly, but not listed under a namespace.  Looking in regedit, I can see that MyAsmNamespace.MyClass is registered, but I cannot find MySecondClass anywhere.

Does MySecondClass have to be in a namespace to be referenced in classic asp or is there a default namespace it becomes a part of?

Comment: Does the second class have any attributes, like `ComVisible`? Any other differences, besides the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

After several days working on this, I have not found a way to reference a class inside an assembly using CreateObject if that class was not placed inside of a namespace.